# How to add CSS dynamically to the Menu Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to Highlight the Menu Dynamically in Html Pages using Js.

For Example

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul id="myid">
    <li id="m1"><a href="company.html">COMPANY</a></li>
    <li id="m2" class="has-sub"><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Enterprise Solution</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="sap.html">SAP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="oracle.html">Oracle</a></li>
                </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

I given Like this. But its not working

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cssmenu ul li").click(function() {

        $(this).addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');

    });
});
```

For this i would like activate the Menu when it is Clicked Using Js. Please Help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: your html markup is wrong

Comment: The `<ul>` element requires a closing tag. It is possible, that the browser fails to build the DOM the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I have a demo for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/ttaN2/4/

I have altered the HTML so that there are correct open and close tags:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul id="myid">
        <li id="m1"><a href="company.html">COMPANY</a></li>
        <li id="m2" class="has-sub"><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">Enterprise Solution</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="sap.html">SAP</a></li>
                <li><a href="oracle.html">Oracle</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I believe this is what you intended. I am not sure what you intended to happen when you click on another sub menu though. I'll try to help you out if you can describe exactly what you intend to happen.

Comment: That HTML is not correct. `<ul>` as a direct child of an other `<ul>`?

Comment: True, I've changed the HTML to what I believe was intended. The jsFiddle still exhibits strange behaviour, but there are some ambiguities in the question so I'm not sure this is what was intended.

Comment: Well, now you just forgot to include jQuery. Also since the menu is hierarchical, it is not enough to just remove the class from the siblings. Also you might want to prevent the event from bubbling, as this way the parent menus will get selected. Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ttaN2/3/).

Comment: Or since only the leafs have links in the original example, you might only want to be able to select those: [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ttaN2/4/)!

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake. And yeah, that does make more sense - I'll make that fiddle the demo